# Yet another Maven assembly plugin exclusion question

Tags: maven

My goal is to create a single jar with dependencies, but exclude some dependencies. The broader context is - I have a single project from which I want to generate a server jar and a client jar. The client jar will use only a small subset of the packages of the server jar. I have no problem generating both jars. The problem is the exclusion.

So to troubleshoot I have stripped everything down to the bare minimum and I can't get that to work.

I have a pom, which references an assembly XML with exclusions. Here's the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.me</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>test</name>

  <properties>
    <jme3_g>org.jmonkeyengine</jme3_g>
    <jme3_v>3.2.0-stable</jme3_v>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${jme3_g}</groupId>
      <artifactId>jme3-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jme3_v}</version>
      <!--scope>provided</scope-->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <!-- JME -->
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>client</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>
                    this.is.just.a.Pom
                  </mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>client</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

An here is the exclusion XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies-and-exclude-classes</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact> <!-- was true -->
            <unpack>false</unpack> <!-- was true -->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>com.foo:bar</exclude>
                <exclude>org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-core</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

The steps I follow are:

1. make a test directory
2. drop these two files into the directory
3. cd into the directory

```
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz zzzz 1059 Mar 12 20:29 jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz zzzz 2169 Mar 12 20:51 pom.xml
```

Then: `mvn clean package`

Note the following output of the maven command:

```
...
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: jar-with-deps-with-exclude.xml
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact exclusion filter:
o  'com.foo:bar'
...
```

I put an exclusion in that wouldn't find anything to validate that Maven was successfully processing the exclusions. It complained about com.foo:bar, but not about org.jmonkeyengine:jme3-core.

When maven finishes:

```
$ jar tf target/client.jar | grep jme | wc -l
825
```

But if I modify the POM and change the JME scope to "provided" then after `mvn clean package`:

```
$ jar tf target/client.jar | grep jme | wc -l
0
```

So it seems to me that the exclusion should have the effect of not including the JME artifact. I'm not sure how to proceed because this seems like the bread and butter use case for dependency exclusion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Creating two different artifacts from the same projects is usually not a good idea. Instead, I would construct a multi-module project with a `client` and a `server` module (and, maybe, a `util` module used by both). Then you can easily create the two executable jars without any exclude hassle.

Comment: Yep I am getting there. I thought I was 99% there with this approach and then this last piece came up so - frustrating to abandon what I have..

Comment: Don't follow the sunken cost fallacy ... it is always good to find something better.